# How to show notifications in a PWA from within the app?

Tags: angular, push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA using Angular 7: http://ramstein-conference-app.herokuapp.com

As it is a conference-app, users can mark events as favorite and see the list of their favorites. However, it would be nice to get notified e.g. half an hour before the event starts. This does not need any server logic and can be done purely inside the PWA itself.

I'm able to show push-notifications via web-Push but **how to show push-notifications from within the PWA itself?**

[swPush](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwPush) doesn't seem to have a method to trigger a notification manually and [navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#add_actions_to_the_notification) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from the [Google Developers Page](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#add_actions_to_the_notification):

```
if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
    var options = {
      body: 'Here is a notification body!',
      icon: 'images/example.png',
      vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
      data: {
        dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
        primaryKey: 1
      },
      actions: [
        {action: 'explore', title: 'Explore this new world',
          icon: 'images/checkmark.png'},
        {action: 'close', title: 'Close notification',
          icon: 'images/xmark.png'},
      ]
    };
    reg.showNotification('Hello world!', options);
  });
}
```