# Create React App PWA Push Notifications on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Is it possible to send a PWA installed on an Android phone push notifications with CRA?

**Constraints:**

1. Create React App
2. Registered service worker to turn into PWA
3. PWA Installed on Android as a "fake/PWA" native app

Answer (score 2):

You can send notifications to your service worker using push notification API .
You can send notifications to a react app using the service worker mechanism.
You can get a service worker pre-configured by generating the code with Create React App. [More details about CRA service-worker here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/).

```
 `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa`.
```

In order to add push notifications you will need to implement a listener inside your business logic that will trigger the notification (a processing result, a button push... etc) then you can trigger the notification as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56788313/12678128).

check the documentation : https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks mate I'm new here this is my very first answer